# defining sources in IntelliJ.. im confused

Tags: intellij-idea

It "looks" like I have done everything right setting up source and resource folders, but still IntelliJ does not seem to "see" the ext folder.

Any clues?

Thanks..

[image]

- update1
  Added ext as library... and no go

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to add saltybits as a library: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-library

Comment: Thanks KA..   I just added ext as a library and still not going..  any ideas?

Comment: btw, the ext folder has only class files. I don't have the sources for that.    I can compile this with TextPad no problems.  The IDEs are finicky. I tried first with Eclipse.. and did not enjoy the experience. IntelliJ seems a nicer experience then eclipse this far.

Comment: Please share a sample project.

Comment: ok I will prepare something simple. But im super busy next day, will take a day or 2..  thanks